# Right way to allow a user to download a file when its URL is generated

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

Situation:

- File is located on AWS S3
- User presses button to download a file
- Request is sent to the server
- Server in response sends generated URL that grants access to the file

  - The URL of course links to another domain (to the S3 bucket)

Current solution:

- Right now JS handler changes the window's location to the received URL.
- File is downloaded as it should.
- But browsers throws errors like:

  - Chrome: *“Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream”*
  - Safari: *“Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted”*

I cannot replace the button with the simple `<a href="url" download>`  because the URL is generated in response to user's request and it is not known in advance.

I want it to be a *one-click experience* (i.e., I don't want the user to click a new button with the received URL).

---

**Question:**

- What is the right way to allow a user to download a file when its URL is generated?
- Is it OK to change the `window.location` for that purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It not sound right to change `window.location` for download file..

If you using a `<a>` tag you can add the [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

```
 <a href="my.pdf" download="your.pdf" >download file</a>
```

If you prefer using code, you can use script like this:

```
 var aTag = document.createElement('a');
 aTag.setAttribute('download','your.pdf');
 aTag.setAttribute('href','my.pdf');
 aTag.click();
```

Comment: doesn't fix the issue: the new tab flickers for a fraction of a second and closes with no download initiated.

Answer (score 0):

Right way is make backend send proper `Content-Type` header with correct MIME type of file on link download request.

It is ok to change `window.location` or `document.location.href` for page redirect to download link.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very simple problem that needs no Javascript at all.

When the request is sent to the server by simply clicking a link to make the request, the server -- after validating the request, generates a signed URL, then responds...

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/... # new signed URL
```

The browser follows the redirect and fetches the resource.

Answer (score 0):

- If you can perform **GET** request for the received URL (*download URL*):

Just open a new tab:

```
window.open(downloadUrl, "_blank");
```

This way the browser starts downloading the file, then the new tab will be automatically closed.

- If you are obligated to perform **POST** request for *download URL*:

Temporary inject the hidden form into your current page, then submit it:

```js
var form = $('<form action="' + downloadUrl + '" method="POST" target="_blank">'
+ '<input name="param1" value="value1" />'
+ '</form>');

form.appendTo(document.body);

$(form).submit();

form.remove();
```

The key here is *target="_blank"* form's attribute. For today, Chrome will automatically close the new tab, while Safari is not. But both download the file.